# Randomly keeping a single element different from zero along one axis of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need an efficient way to create a numpy array of shape (x,y,3) where only one random element out of the 3 for each tuple (x,y) has a value randomly selected from [-1,0,1]

```
 np.random.randint(-1, 2, (x,y,3))
```

does the work only for the second half of my requirements.

I could use a nested loop to iterate on each (x, y) and multiple its value by a random mask but it would not be efficient at all.

Here is the loop implementation:

```
a=np.random.randint(-1, 2, (x,y,3))
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        mask = np.array(np.random.permutation([0,1,0]))
        a[i][j] = a[i][j] * mask
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand.. So you mean that for each row in the inner arrays, only the values in one column are random? Can you show a simple example?

Comment: Yes, please show with for loop

Comment: Done as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than generating a whole bunch of extra numbers and turning most of them off, I'd approach this from the point of view of only generating the numbers you need. You want to assign to a random index between 0 and 2 for each x-y pair. So generate a random index, and the random values, and assign:

```
indices = np.random.randint(3, size=(x, y))
values = np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=(x, y))
result = np.zeros((x, y, 3), dtype=int)
result[(*np.ogrid[:x, :y], indices)] = values
```

The indexing expression is an [advanced index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) because `indices` is a list of integers. Using `...` or `:, :` for the first two indices won't do what you want in that case. Instead, [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html)  generates ranges of the correct shape to force the elements of `indices` to correspond to the correct x-y coordinates.

Comment: I tried your code, it seems to work! I'll have to understand it :)